# Dynamic controls in angular 8 with different labels

Tags: typescript, angular-material

Here, i am creating dynamic controls in my form. Controls are creating, But i am not able give individual labels text . Please help me out

```
   <div [formGroup]="dynamicctrls">
                                <div formArrayName="inptctls">
                                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" style="width: 350px;" *ngFor='let itmin of inptctls.controls;let i=index'>
                                        <mat-label>Label name</mat-label>
                                        <input type="text" matInput>
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </div>
                            </div>
 


  dynamicctrls = this.fb.group({
    inptctls: this.fb.array([
      this.fb.control(''),
      this.fb.control('')
    ])
  });
```

Comment: You can create a formGroup instead of a formControl and give it two controls, one for input, the other for label, which should be readonly.

Comment: I created form controls itself in the way of creating form group. thanks @ritaj